# Calendar. Recurrent event occurrence. How to check if start date matched on pattern?

Tags: java, icalendar, find-occurrences, rfc5545, ical4j

If I use google library [*google-rfc-2445*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-saddle/google-rfc-2445/20110304) (to calculate occurrences)

```
String sRule = "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=3;INTERVAL=2;BYMONTH=5;BYMONTHDAY=22,23,24,25,26,27,28;BYDAY=MO";
LocalDateIterable localDateIterable = LocalDateIteratorFactory
            .createLocalDateIterable(sRule, org.joda.time.LocalDate.now(), true);
LocalDateIterator iterator = localDateIterable.iterator();
iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

I'll get in result:

> 2017-07-17
>
> 2019-05-27
>
> 2021-05-24
>
> 2023-05-22

considering pattern, there are should be only 3 dates. Considering each one we can find that first one is redundant. I have no marker if start date is valid or not. And as you see first one isn't. (If I use correct start date creating iterable I would get 3 correct dates in result.)

Similar experiment with *[lib-recur](https://github.com/dmfs/lib-recur)* (result almost similar with small differences)

```
RecurrenceRule recurrenceRule = new RecurrenceRule("FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=23;BYMONTH=5;COUNT=3");
RecurrenceRuleIterator it = recurrenceRule.iterator(DateTime.nowAndHere());
int maxInstances = 10; // limit instances for rules that recur forever
while (it.hasNext() && (!recurrenceRule.isInfinite() || maxInstances-- > 0)) {
    DateTime nextInstance = it.nextDateTime();
    System.out.println(nextInstance);
}
```

Result count is correct, but first occurrence isn't. Correctness of first occurrence depends on (if start date is correct first occurrence also would be correct)...

> 20170717T123104
>
> 20190527T123104
>
> 20210524T123104

How I could specify or validate start date in correct way using [*google-rfc-2445*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-saddle/google-rfc-2445/20110304) or *[lib-recur](https://github.com/dmfs/lib-recur)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-54) states

> The "DTSTART" property for a "VEVENT" specifies the inclusive
> start of the event.  For recurring events, it also specifies the
> very first instance in the recurrence set.

That's why `lib-recur` always adds the start instance.

However, we have an open issue about that (see [issue 22](https://github.com/dmfs/lib-recur/issues/22)) and I've come to the conclusion that it's better design to iterate only the instances of the rule and add the start instances at a later stage (in `RecurrenceSet` to be specific). That's also what RFC 5545 seems to suggest.

I'll take care of this and it will be "fixed" in version 0.10

Comment: FTR: Version 0.10 has just been released and `RecurrenceRuleIterator` no longer returns start instances not matching the `RRULE`.